# Why do pigul, nosar, and tame incur kares?

Tags: korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, karet

As described in e.g. *Rambam hilchos Pisule Hamukdashin* chapter 18, there are bunch of things that render a *korban* invalid, and someone who eats from it gets whipped. However, there are three types of invalid *korban* that someone who eats gets *kares*: a *korban* that was prepared with intent to eat it beyond the specified time, a *korban* when eaten beyond the specified time, and a *korban* eaten by someone *tame*. (Others, that don't incur *kares*, are a *korban* that's *tame*, a *korban* prepared with intent to eat it in the wrong place, and an animal with a physical blemish.)

Why do those invalidations, specifically, incur *kares*, when other invalidations don't? I'm seeking a *taame-hamitzvos* reason, not a how-do-we-know (what's-the-*d'rasha*) reason.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if he had a source, but a Rebbe of mine - Rav Yitzchok Fruchter of Jerusalem -  explained this concept at various times.

> There are three types of invalid korban that someone who eats gets kares: a korban that was prepared with intent to eat it beyond the specified time, a korban when eaten beyond the specified time, and a korban eaten by someone *tame*.

These 3 cases are done for the sake of doing a Mitzva.

The person knows he can't finish it on time - or the time has already passed - but he feels that it's a big Mitzva to finish eating this Korban instead of burning it.

Similarly, the impure - *Tame* - person is trying to help eat the Korban so it doesn't go to waste.

This type of *being more righteous than the King* (who explicitly forbade it) warrants a more severe punishment, to prevent people from doing these Mitzva-Aveirot. Otherwise they may just decide that it's worth getting lashes in order to fulfill the important Mitzva of eating the korban.